# Code still runs using old version of Python

Tags: python, version

I have installed python 2.7 on my CentOS server.
When I go into the python command line it tells me I'm using 2.7.
When I issue a python -v command it reports 2.7.
But when I run the script I'm working on and get it to output the version (using import sys   print(sys.version)) in use it reports the old version (2.4).

Can anyone help me get it to run the code against the new version.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you execute the script? Does it have a shebang line in the beginning that tells it to use a specific python?

Comment: What does the first line of your script say?  The shebang (`#!`) line?  That will tell the script which version of the interpreter to run.

Comment: How do you run it, and how is that different from when you run python from the command line? Maybe use `which python` at the `bash` prompt to determine where you're getting command-line python from.

Comment: I've now run into another issue. The new python 2.7 I've installed needs some additions (cahrdet and MySQLDB etc). I'm trying to install setuptools but it keeps installing to the old 2.4 directory. I'm assuming that there is some PATH somwhere but I can'd find it. ech $PATH has no reference to Python. Does anyone know where this is? I've also looked in /ect/profile.

Comment: @Columbo You should write a new question to address that completely separate issue. But long story short, if you're working with multiple versions of python you should look at virtualenv: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: Thanks Wilduck, looking at that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the first line of your script.

The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line (first in the script) will explain to your shell which interpreter it should use in order to execute the contents of the file.

When I write scripts for myself I usually use:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Which uses which ever python interpreter is in my environment settings.  Since I use `virtualenv`, this is a local customized version of my python install by default, but can be easily switched based on context.